# Things are centered in Firefox but not IE or Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

Alright I've tried to post the code but its not working. We have a table that contains the tabs for our website. In firefox its perfect. In IE its not. The link to the site is http://www.unitedbygaming.com/ Its much easier if you just go there and look at the page source than for me to post it here. Thanks for the help in advance. Im an amateur coder so I have no idea why this would occur. Also ignore that the tabs link to pages that look like garbage. We're getting what each page should look like finalized before we do anything else. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Looks centered to me in Chrome and IE. In fact, it's exactly the same as how Firefox renders it.

Comment: Do you know what version of each of those browsers you are using? Also could you tell me what your resolution is?

Comment: 1440x900 and 1360x768. Chrome 16.0.912.77. Firefox 9.0.1. IE 9.0.8112. All under Windows7.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to center thing try this works for me.
specify the width and height

```
width:1000px;
height:300px;  
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
top:50%
margin-left:-500px;
```

as you can notice -500px means half of your width;

Comment: just specified a width and height and it still doesn't work. Thanks for the help. Any other ideas.